# How do I get Jenkins running on Linux to communicate with Windows servers?

Tags: jenkins, devops

How do I get Jenkins running on Linux to communicate with Windows servers?
Currently Jenkins running in Linux and WebSphere running on windows and both are on prem not in cloud 
i need to deploy War file which generated by Linux Jenkins to windows WebSphere, and client not agreeing for 3rd party tools like open-ssh and pscp 
so , pls let me know if any one have idea to implement this ..

Thanks

Comment: Please follow the link - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+agent+machines+on+Windows

Comment: Also read my response to [Unable to get "launch agent via java web start" option in the launch mod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56980939/598141)